# TO_NUMBER invalid number error

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I have searched for and seen some similar questions, but none have solved my problem.  I am getting a invalid number error on my TO_NUMBER in my where clause.  Some things I have read said that it can be caused by where you place the TO_NUMBER in your where clause, so I was hoping someone could help me solve this.  Here is the where clause in my query:

```
WHERE year_sec = TEST.YEAR_SEC_BY_DATE ('F', 0)
   AND (year_sec = '2014F')
    AND ((no_name LIKE '54%' AND user3 IS NOT NULL)
     OR (SUBSTR (no_name, 1, 2) = '52' AND SUBSTR (no_name, 5, 1) = '8')
     OR (no_name LIKE '56%')) 
OR (TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(year_sec,1,4), '9999') >= 2015)
     AND ((no_name LIKE '543%' AND user3 IS NOT NULL)
      OR (no_name LIKE '523%')
      OR (no_name LIKE '563%'));
```

year_sec is always 4 digits with one letter after, and never null (if it isn't then there would be much bigger problems).  So can anyone see why this would be causing the ORA-01722 error?

EDIT: Removed quotes, error while copying over sql.

Comment: @Gordon that was an accident while copying the sql over.  With the quotes removed, I still get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure it refers to the same line?

Comment: I just ran it again, and got [Error] Execution (17: 19): ORA-01722: invalid number
The referenced spot is the start of the SUBSTR function on the line starting with OR (TO_NUMBER...

Comment: It does not matter where in what order you put predicates in the where clause, the DBMS is free to evaluate them in any order. Are you sure that `SUBSTR(year_sec,1,4)` is always a number? What is the result of `select SUBSTR(year_sec,1,4) from ... where SUBSTR(year_sec,1,1) NOT BETWEEN '0' AND '9' OR SUBSTR(year_sec,2,1) NOT BETWEEN '0' AND '9' OR ...` for all four positions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the error is coming from the `to_number` in your query and not, for example, from an invalid conversion in the `year_sec_by_date` function or somewhere else in your code, I would generally wager that Oracle is too dumb to lie to you.  Somewhere in your data, you have at least one row where `year_sec` isn't a 4 digit number followed by a letter.

One way of finding the problem row would be to

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_to_number( p_str IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN to_number( p_str );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

and then

```
SELECT year_sec, <<other columns>>
  FROM <<your table>>
 WHERE my_to_number( substr( year_sec, 1, 4 )) IS NULL
```

Note that if you have some rows where the `year_sec` is invalid that are being filtered out by other predicates in your query, there is no guarantee that Oracle will apply predicates in any particular order.  Oracle may apply the `to_number` before or after any other predicate in the query.

Comment: Oracle doesnt have a ISNUMERIC function?

Comment: @Mihai - Not a built-in, no.  You could also write a quick regular expression to find rows that have non-numeric data.

Comment: NOT(REGEXP_LIKE(year_sec, '\d{4}\w'))

Comment: Or use `translate()` for a quick way to detect numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer can rewrite your query and change where you expect the conversion to occur. Check for bad character data where you expect numeric data.

```
SELECT year_sec,
       UPPER(SUBSTR(year_sec,1,4)) AS UPPER_YEAR,
       LOWER(SUBSTR(year_sec,1,4)) AS LOWER_YEAR
  FROM my_table
 WHERE UPPER(SUBSTR(year_sec,1,4)) != LOWER(SUBSTR(year_sec,1,4))
```

[From OraFAQ ORA-01722](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-01722)